# Python: Join dataframes issues

Tags: python, dataframe, append, concatenation

With this 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": ["ID0", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3"],
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
    },
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": ["ID0", "ID1", "ID2", "ID4"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C4"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D4"],
    },
)
```

My goal is to join them, not havind repeated ID's and have None when there's no information:

```
ID  A   B   C   D
ID0 A0  B0  C0  D0
ID1 A1  B1  C1  D1
ID2 A2  B2  C2  D2
ID3 A3  B3  None None
ID4 None None C4 D4
```

Whate are the .concat parameters to do this, Have tried several but without the result that I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) instead:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='outer')
```

Output:

```
    ID    A    B    C    D
0  ID0   A0   B0   C0   D0
1  ID1   A1   B1   C1   D1
2  ID2   A2   B2   C2   D2
3  ID3   A3   B3  NaN  NaN
4  ID4  NaN  NaN   C4   D4
```

This will have Nans where values are missing.